# Python: exception of type index error?

Tags: python, indexing, conditional-statements

I have to write small sections of code for an introductory programming class I'm taking - I had no trouble until I tried this one. The code works fine so far as I can tell but I keep getting the IndexError, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
vowel = {"a", "e", "o", "i", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
word = input("Enter a phrase: ")

if word[0] in vowel:
    print("an", word)
else:
    print("a", word)
```

EDIT:
The code's working perfectly now, all I needed was the additional if statement for an empty string, as per your suggestions

Comment: When do you get the error? Is is specific inputs (since you don't check first if word is an empty string, trying to index the first character will throw and Index out of range error)?

Comment: Apparently it occurs on line 4?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exact error you are getting. You mention `IndexError` which would normally be raised for an index that is out of range. In your code, the only place where I could see such problem might exist is `word[0]`. But that would only happen if no word has been entered. I assume that your code is just an example and that a word is always entered.

You are also defining a set (`vowel`) using the curly braces notation and that might be a problem for some old python (before 2.7).

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment I'm pretty sure it is actually about the word not being entered. So, no to solve your test problem for you completely, I will just say that you should consider the case when `word` is empty in your program as well.

Comment: The class I'm taking has us use a website called Grok instead of just plain Python, so I think it runs the latest version of Python but I'm not sure - I'll change it back to square brackets in any case. As for the error, the website marks code on the spot and whenever I try to submit this piece it says 'your submission has raised an exception of type indexerror' -  despite this none of the inputs I've tried using have actually failed to produce the right output

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you're getting at - when I didn't enter a word it came up with an error regarding range. Would this be fixed by trying to specify a range for my variable vowel?

Comment: Basically, you should just make another conditional statement to check for the special case of word being empty. In python empty strings are `False`, so checking `if word` should do. You should handle that special case gracefully, although I am not sure how, since I do not know what exactly is expected of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check for null input, meaning the test system is just hitting enter rather than entering an actual string. When you try to index the first character of an empty string you will get an index error. Try something similar to:

```
vowel = {"a", "e", "o", "i", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
word = input("Enter a phrase: ")
if word == "":
    print("please enter a word")
elif word[0] in vowel:
    print("an", word)
else:
    print("a", word)
```

You should check if the assignment has any instructions on how to handle empty strings.