# How to overcome the error of 'exception of type IndexError'?

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

I have to get an specific output for a specific input as shown below:

```
code: soMe SuPPLies liKE Ice-cREAm aRe iMPORtant oNly tO THeir cReaTORS. tO DestroY thEm iS pOInTLess.
says: destroy their ice-cream supplies
```

I wrote a program below:

```
line = input("code: ")
words = line.split()
human = words[11] + ' ' + words[8] + ' ' + words[3] + ' ' + words[1]
print('says:',human.lower())
```

While I am getting the desired output, the compiler is giving me an error - 'Your submission raised an exception of type IndexError. This occurred on line 3 of your submission.'

Please help me.

Comment: You probably want to add a check for null values too as mentioned here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021740/python-exception-of-type-index-error)

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new to Python, could you please elaborate further or add/modify my code?

Comment: If your input is constant, then it's better to declare it as a string. Since you are using `input`, there is a chance that the user does not input anything or the user inputs a sentence with just 3 words. In this case, `words[11]` `words[8]` etc will be not be present at all. This is when you get an `list index is out of range` error.

Comment: This program is specifically for the given input. My code is giving the correct output but giving the error - IndexError'. It is not giving any out of range error.